# prove the inequality $0< \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p}< \frac{47}{60}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I have an Olympiad Problem, let $m$, $n$ and $p$ denote three natural numbers where:

$$m>n>p>2$$

prove that :

$$0< \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p}< \frac{47}{60}$$

I've been trying to find a proof of the inequalities above but every time I am getting stucked with the $\frac{47}{60}$. Could you please provide a hint about that or complete proof?

Comment: $\frac 13 +\frac 14 +\frac 15=\frac {47}{60}$.

Comment: Taking $m,n,p$ as $2.3,2.2,2.1$ respectively does not satisfy the inequality. As the example by lulu suggests, do you mean that $m,n,p$ are integers?

Answer (score 6):

**For natural numbers.** It is clear that $3\leq p$, similarly, $4\leq n$, and $5\leq m$. Thus, $\frac 13\geq \frac 1p$, similarly, $\frac 14\geq \frac1n$, and $\frac 15\geq \frac 1m$. Adding these gives you $$\frac13+\frac14+\frac15\geq\frac 1p+\frac 1m+\frac1n$$ which gives us the final result
$$\frac 1p+\frac 1m+\frac1n\leq \frac{47}{60}$$
Note that this is not the result you wished for, as you wanted a strict inequality. Unfortunately equality is being reached for $(m,n,p)=(5,4,3)$ so we cannot make the inequality strict. The lower bound is trivial as all terms are positive.

---

**For real numbers.** As mentioned, this is not true, take for example $(p,n,m)=(2.1,2.2,2.3)$.

Comment: thanks , I corrected it, it only works for naturals